# How to install Otto on Mac OS X to work in the command line?

Tags: otto

How to install Otto on Mac OS X to work in the command line (i.e. by simply typing `otto`)?

Answer (score 0):

After downloading the 32 or 64bit binary [here](https://www.ottoproject.io/intro/getting-started/install.html), the file then needs to be findable by shell if it is to be used simply by typing `otto`. This is mentioned in the documentation but does not go into detail, and there are conventions when it comes to adding these kind of binary files to you PATH environment that are worth mentioning.

Before adding another location to your system's environmental PATH variable, your Mac might already have folders that it searches through every time a command is run. Here are some standard locations the otto binary file can be placed without adding more locations to the PATH variable:

/bin

/usr/bin

/usr/sbin

/usr/local/bin